# Thymeleaf does not factor in Spring @NumberFormat when displaying values

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use @NumberFormat annotation on some fields to get them displayed in the desired format. This works fine with JSP if I use `<s:eval>` to display the values.

How can I do the same with thymeleaf?

Comment: Have you had a look here ? :
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers

Comment: I would have to take care of formatting manually everywhere (duplicating what I already defined with @NumberFormat on java side) if I use thymeleaf formatters. I was just wondering if thymeleaf would honor spring formatters  similar to jsp <s:eval>

Comment: You could raise an issue with the Thymeleaf team.  In the meantime, if you are using Thymeleaf v2.1 or higher, you could simply add a custom `org.springframework.format.Formatter` (from `spring-context.jar`) to your Spring configuration and then use the `${{bean.numberProperty}}` syntax to print numeric fields of a specific type in a common format.  This is explained in detail in the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#spconv).